# How fill a field when select an option using forms.ModelChoice in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model Product that has a field price , I need make in a form that when the user select a Product ,  in the price field , show  the price  the product selected

This is the form.py

```
class FacturaForm(forms.Form):
    product = forms.ModelChoice(queryset=product.objects.all())
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()
    price = forms.DecimalField()
```

How I can fill the product'price  when a user select a product